# Ordering a list SQL or Excel

Tags: sql, excel, list

I have a simple task to do at work almost daily and I think it can be done easily with some help. There is a table with a single column "PC name". I have to divide the list of PC's into waves.

```
Wave 1 : 2%  
wave 2:  3%  
wave 3: 25%  
wave 4: 45%  
wave 5: 25%
```

So what I usually do is to copy the list of PC's into Excel and add a column named "wave assign". So for example if the list is 100 PC's first two PC's will be assign to `Wave 1`, three PCs to`wave 2`, 25 PCs to `wave 3` and so on.

I need a way to automate this since it takes me too long to do it manually. It doesn't matter if there is a small change in the % in order to round up the number of PCs in each wave.

Comment: Is the PC list static?

Comment: Which database and version are you using?

Comment: Hi! I am using access 2010 or excel 2010. 
Yes, the list is static

Thanks pnuts let me give it a try

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the list is in ColumnA starting in Row1:

```
=VLOOKUP(ROWS(A$1:A1)/COUNTA(A:A),wArray,2)
```

in Row1 and copied down should work, provided a lookup array of the following kind is created:

[image: SO18596249 example]

and named `wArray`.

In case the list is shorter than 100 I have added .002 to the 'logical' breakpoints (cumulative proportions) so that it is not the minority waves that are rounded down such that, at say 50 items, Wave 1 does not feature (and hence stand out rather more than an approximation in a larger group).